# how to import data in Excel to couch DB

Tags: couchdb

I have an assignment to do about bundesliga, it is very large data. The data (like club details, player stats, etc)is very huge. so do I have any option to import data from Excel to CouchDB?

Comment: You have to add way more details, you have to include what have you tried so far, what didn't work and why - just then people will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for club records (not football) with Couchbase. The 3rd party host of the data provided an excel spreadsheet dump. I loaded it into Couchbase using Eclipse, java, and the org.apache.poi and the com.google.gson libraries.

I simply stepped through the tabs and the columns picking up the data I needed.

You will probably have to do some programming to get the data into the format you want. I don't think that there's a straight import capability.